# Input type to allow only numbers and maxLength

Tags: html, input, ionic3

I have an input type, and i want it to allow only numbers with a maxLenght limit using ionic 3.

I have tried this:

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="5" class="correos-custom-input {{isEmpty}}" [disabled]="isPCVerified" [(ngModel)]="postalCode">
```

this allows me to write numbers and letters with a maxLenght.

```
<input type="number" maxlength="5" class="correos-custom-input {{isEmpty}}" [disabled]="isPCVerified" [(ngModel)]="postalCode">
```

and this just numbers but with an unlimited lenght because maxlenght is just supported for type text and tel.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular Form Validators.  For your number problem, you could simply change it to text, then in the module, convert to a number before saving it.

The other option is to create your own validator and extend it from the current number validator and add your own length check.  I found this [article](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/advanced-topics/basic-custom-validators/) as a sample for email, but it can be easily modified to add the length check.

Another good example to create your own [custom validator](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

I used this same method in ionic 1 and 3. Please try.

.html file

```
<ion-input type="tel" maxlength="10" [(ngModel)]="telNumber" (keyup)="iskeyUpNumber($event)"></ion-input>
```

.ts file

```
iskeyUpNumber(evt)
{
   this.telNumber= isNaN(this.telNumber) ? this.telNumber.slice(0, -1)  : this.telNumber.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="5" inputmode="numeric" pattern="^[0-9]*$" class="correos-custom-input {{isEmpty}}" [disabled]="isPCVerified" [(ngModel)]="postalCode">
```

`inputmode` will tell the input to show the numeric keyboard on device, `pattern` is a regex of the expected entry, in this case only numbers.

Hope this helps.